# To write a Oracle stored procedure to get data between the months

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have a procedure sp_data_between_months (p_from_date DATE, p_to_date DATE) // example p_from_date = '01-jan-2021' and 'p_to_date' = '31-mar-2021'.
I need to get the latest record for the ID for each month, add these values, and populate against p_to_date for each ID from the below table using PLSQL.
Table Name: ID_Value

| ID | Date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-jan-2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 10-jan-2021 | 20 |
| 2 | 15-jan-2021 | 15 |
| 2 | 16-jan-2021 | 20 |
| 2 | 02-feb-2021 | 10 |
| 2 | 06-feb-2021 | 15 |
| 1 | 17-feb-2021 | 10 |
| 1 | 5-mar-2021 | 15 |
| 1 | 17-mar-2021 | 10 |
| 2 | 10-mar-2021 | 10 |

the expected output is to get the latest value for each ID for each month-end and the sum of its value between those months between the ranges.

Output: p_to_date ID  Sum of latest record of value for each month

| DATE | ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31-Mar-2021 | 1 | 40 //(20+10+10) sum of value oflatest record foreach month |
| 31-Mar-2021 | 2 | 45 //(20+15+10) |

Comment: what have you tried and where do you stuck?

Comment: Your message is **difficult to read**. Please, edit it so that we'd at least see what you have.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I have made the problem clear now, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with
  2  temp as
  3    -- analytic function will return 1 for the latest row for that ID in that month
  4    (select id, datum, value,
  5        row_number() over (partition by id, trunc(datum, 'mm') order by datum desc) rn
  6     from id_value
  7    )
  8    -- finally, select last day in MAX month and sum all values for RN = 1
  9  select
 10    id,
 11    last_day(max(datum)) datum,
 12    sum(value)
 13  from temp
 14  where rn = 1
 15  group by id;

        ID DATUM       SUM(VALUE)
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 31-mar-2021         40
         2 31-mar-2021         45

SQL>
```